# How to manage start/stop of docker-compose services when instance is not used

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose

How to manage start/stop of docker-compose services when AWS instance is not used
We use docker-compose services during 9AM - 6PM, but would like to stop during the rest of the day

How to start/stop services when they are not needed

Comment: This is `docker-compose` running on a single EC2 instance? Or are you doing something like docker-compose deployment to Elastic Beanstalk or ECS?

Comment: docker-compose running on a single EC2 instance

Comment: Do you want to shutdown the entire EC2 server during that time? Or just stop the `docker-compose` services?

Comment: shut down the entire EC2 server during that time, to save costs

Comment: See this post https://serverfault.com/questions/867642/how-to-start-and-stop-aws-ec2-instance-based-on-a-time-based-schedule

Comment: feels like a combination of `EC2 Scheduler` and docker-compose `restart:always` flag would cover the use case

Answer (score 0):

On a modern Linux system you can use [systemd socket activation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) to start a service on-demand. For example you could put this in `my-docker-service.socket`.

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=443 # listen on HTTPS port both on ipv4 and ipv6
Accept=no # Don't spawn a new instance for each incoming connection

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target 

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/docker-compose # the service to start with arguments
User=docker
Group=docker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding restart policy in the docker-compose.yml file, so whenever you start the server, the docker containers will restart themselves.

add line restart: always

```
webserver:
  image: xxxxx
  user: user-name (Optional)
  restart: always
  ....
```

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

I have always used this policy and all the containers come up after server reboots.

Comment: How would the server know where the docker-compose file is and how does it know how to restart

Comment: It will be handled by docker service, not server. When you run docker-compose up -d from the directory where docker-compose.yml, the containers will be created with the restart policy.